# Want to use imagecopy or imagecopyresampled with 50% opacity

Tags: php, gd

I am using PHP GD `imagecopy` or `imagecopyresampled` to merge a PNG image with transparency onto another PNG image (basically creating t-shirt mockups with design).

When I use imagecopymerge() it doesn't respect the transparency. but opacity setting option works. But when I use `imagecopy()` or `imagecopyresampled()` then transparency works but opacity setting is not available.

So how to merge images which respects transparency and provides 50% opacity as well?

My code is:

```
$img1 = imagecreatefrompng('m1.png');
$img2 = imagecreatefrompng('m2.png');

imagealphablending( $img2, false );
imagesavealpha( $img2, true );

$x1 = imagesx($img1);
$y1 = imagesy($img1);
$x2 = imagesx($img2);
$y2 = imagesy($img2);

//imagecopyresampled($img1, $img2, 205, 170, 0, 0, $x2-40, $y2-40, $x2, $y2);
imagecopy($img1, $img2, 205, 170, 0, 0, $x2-40, $y2-40);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img1);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this link:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=23815

imagecopymerge doesn't support image alpha. Becuase of that, they have requested the creation of a new function imagecopymergealpha to do this kind of job.

https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/211

Answer (score 0):

```
imagecopymerge($img1, $img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, 50);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check using this sample code

```
$imageName = 'path/to/your/image/file'
$im_src = create_image_from_type($imageName);
$size = getimagesize($imageName);
$im_dst = create_image_from_type($imageName);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im_dst, 255, 255, 255);
imagecolortransparent($im_dst, $white);
imagefilledrectangle($im_dst, 0, 0, $size[0], $size[1], $white);
$opacityVal = 50;// put the opacity value here
imagecopymerge($im_dst, $im_src, 0, 0, 0, 0,$size[0], $size[1], $opacityVal);
save_image($im_dst, $imageName, 100);
```